# Kotlin Flow: Chunking flows and wait until chunk finished before starting a new one

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I can't find a way to create some algorithm to implement chunked flow launching.
The feature is simple - I want to show user the download progress of his multiple files

- user enters some resource urls he wants to download
- for each url I create a flow and make request and wrap each url request in `Flow<DownloadState>`
- as the result in my presentation layer I have `List<Flow<DownloadState>>` that I merge and get `Flow<DownloadState>`

My question is - if I have `List<Flow<DownloadState>>`, can I split them into parts and start them by parts instead of launching them all at once?

I've tried `chunked` from list, but couldn't implement it properly.
I googled similar solutions from RxJava, but I haven't found anything that could help me

upd: other way of saying: I want to limit the number of concurrent downloads.

Comment: Do you want to chunk to limit the number of concurrent downloads or chunking is somehow related to your presentation layer?

Comment: @broot the first one, i want to limit the number of concurrent downloads, so files would download by pairs, for example. not all of them in parallel

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I feel presentation layer shouldn't be involved in things like limiting the concurrency of downloading. I think service layer should limit the concurrency, e.g. by using a Semaphore and then presentation layer gets a `Flow<DownloadState>`. If you want to follow your initial approach, then I believe chunking already merged flows is not possible. According to `merge()` docs, it starts collecting all flows concurrently, you can't limit it afterwards. You would need to chunk before merging, so e.g. chunk a list and then create a flow of these chunks. But...

Comment: But I don't think chunking is really what you need here. That would mean if we chunk e.g. by 4, then we need to process all first 4 files, before going for the 5th one. Instead, you probably need to limit concurrency, not chunk. For limiting the concurrency, see `flattenMerge()` or `flatMapMerge()` - there you can specify how many flows should be consumed concurrently. You can actually use this technique in the service layer as well, instead of a Semaphore suggested above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.chunked(chunkSize: Int): Flow<List<T>> {
    val buffer = mutableListOf<T>()
    return flow {
        this@chunked.collect {
            buffer.add(it)
            if (buffer.size == chunkSize) {
                emit(buffer.toList())
                buffer.clear()
            }
        }
        if (buffer.isNotEmpty()) {
            emit(buffer.toList())
        }
    }
}
```